# How to get the value of const char *

Tags: c, pointers

New to C and trying to understand pointers and how to work with them. I understand a pointer is a reference to memory location and I think I get the basics and simple examples, but how can I assign the value of a const char pointer to a char?

When I try I get warning;

```
incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'char' with an expression of type 'const char *' [-Wint-conversion]
```

I understand the type difference but how do I go about solving it.

Here is the code:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define SUITS 4
#define FACES 13
#define CARDS 52
#define HAND_SIZE 5

struct Card {
    char suit;
    char face;
};

void dealHand(const char *wFace[], struct Card *wHand[]);

int main(void)
{
    //initialize deck array
    unsigned int deck[SUITS][FACES] = {0};

    srand(time(NULL)); // seed random-number generator

    //initialize face array
    const char *face[FACES] = 
        {"Ace", "Deuce", "Three", "Four",
         "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight",
         "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

    struct Card *hand[HAND_SIZE];
    dealHand(face, hand); //deal the deck

}

//deal cards in deck
void dealHand(const char *wFace[], struct Card *wHand[])
{
    unsigned int c = 0;
    char f = wFace[2];
    struct Card aCard;
    aCard.face = f;
    wHand[0] = &aCard;
}
```

I get warning on line:

```
char f = wFace[2];
```

Casting it using (const *) doesn't seem to be a solution.

Comment: _"how can I assign the value of a const char pointer to a char?"_ question is, ___why?___

Comment: to simply get the value at that location. If there is a better way. What is it or what should I look into?

Comment: You might find it easier if you work with identifiers for the cards within the workings of the program (perhaps using `enum`) instead of with their textual names. You can use their textual names just for output to the humans.

Comment: @user2300867 I think what you're looking to do is char f = *wFace[2];
Which will leave the T in the variable f. (T is the first character of the string "Three", which is contained in the array wFace)

Comment: @user2300867 Take a look at the solution below. I guess you need to print the whole name not just a first character of the name. Is that true? If yes the solution below should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I assign the value of a const char pointer to a char?"

You should not do that. You need to print the whole name not just a first character of the name.

You are retrieving the pointer to const string so the code should be like:

`const char *f = wFace[2];`

Also

```
struct Card {
   char suit;
   const char *face;
};
```

and than
`aCard.face = f;` will work.

```
void dealHand(const char *wFace[], struct Card *wHand[])
{
unsigned int c = 0;
const char *f = wFace[2];
struct Card aCard;
aCard.face = f;
wHand[0] = &aCard;
printf( "%s",f);
}
```

Will print:

`Three`

Comment: @user2300867 I assume you want to print wFace[2] which is constant string. To assign constant string to variable use matching type: `const char *`

Comment: Thanks, but is this an OK practice? It seems a bit of a hack.

Comment: No! Not at all! This is a proper assignment! Take a look at:     `const char *nameOfTheCard = "Four";  printf( "%s",nameOfTheCard);`

Answer (score 5):

> char f = wFace[2];

`f` is character, its range probably is [-128,127] (not required).
value of `wFace[2]` is a pointer to memory address.
You are assigning different types here, what did you expect?

---

This is what value of `wFace[2]` could be:

`wFace[2] == 0x1000` some memory address.
And then look at memory

```
Memory address: 0x1000 0x1001 0x1002 0x1003
Value stored:   H      i      !      0
```

If you do `*wFace[2]` it will give you 'H' back; if you do `*(wFace[2]+1)` it will give you 'i' back.

---

What you more likely want is probably:

```
const char *f = wFace[2];
```

Comment: well. I understand that, but how can I get the char value from the pointer

Comment: @user2300867 Dereference the pointer, but it will only give you the first character pointed to by pointer.

Comment: if I can just print the value using printf("%s", wFace[2]) why can't I just assign wFace[2] value to a variable either a string or a char.

Comment: @user2300867 That's a catch, that is how printf works, it will start from the memory pointed by wFace[2] and print all characters till it encounters null terminator.

Comment: thanks for the update. I get why assingment doesn't work but how should I go about being able to retrive the value just like printf does.

Comment: @user2300867 const char *x = wFace[2]; try to better understand what strings are in C and how they "work"